# Pac4j Scala - Multiple SAML2 clients in secure action

Tags: scala, pac4j

I have a `pac4j` `Config` with two `SAML2Client`:

```
val clients = new Clients(baseUrl + "/domain/callback", samlClient1, samlClient2)
val config = new Config(clients)
```

My question:

How do I specify the client I want to use in a secure action if both clients are `SAML2Client`?

```
def SAMLSecure: SecureAction[SAML2Profile, AnyContent, AuthenticatedRequest] =
    Secure(
      clients = "SAML2Client", // How to specify samlClient1 or samlClient2
      authorizers = myAuthorizers,
      matchers = myMatchers
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

```
val samlClient1 = new SAML2Client()
val samlClient2 = new SAML2Client()

samlClient1.setName("SamlClient1")
samlClient2.setName("SamlClient2")

val clients = new Clients(baseUrl + "/domain/callback", samlClient1, samlClient2)
val config = new Config(clients)
```

And then you can define the `SecureAction` like this:

```
def SAMLSecure: SecureAction[SAML2Profile, AnyContent, AuthenticatedRequest] =
    Secure(
      clients = "SamlClient1", // Or "SamlClient2" or both "SamlClient1,SamlClient2"
      authorizers = myAuthorizers,
      matchers = myMatchers
    )
```